# Como exportar Excel con filas y columnas bloqueadas para que no seas modificadas utilizando EPPlus asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

hola comunidad tengo un problema que no he podido resolver espero me puedan ayudar, cualquier sugerencia es muy bien recibida.

Estoy programando en asp.net c# y exporto mis datos a excel usando epplu. Hasta aqui todo correcto.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es bloquear unas columnas y filas(como el encabezado) para que estas no seas modificadas por el usuario final. ¿Alguien puede darme una sugerencia?, ya que lo único que encuentro es la in-movilización de paneles pero esto no me funciona en mi caso.

Gracias.

Este es mi método para exportar el archivo excel.

```
  public void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table, string filename)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Resultados.xlsx");


        using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
            ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            ws.View.FreezePanes(3, 5); // Aquí es donde pretendo bloquear columnas y filas pero este codigo solo me inmoviliza paneles.
            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            pack.SaveAs(ms);
            ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: Con bloquear te referís a proteger las celdas con contraseña?

Comment: Hola @JuanSalvadorPortugal exacto proteger solo algunas columnas completas(hasta donde terminan los datos) o filas sin contraseña para que estas no puedan ser cambiadas por el usuario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, EPPlus tiene todas las celdas bloqueadas, por lo que en caso de querer bloquear sólo algunas, lo que deberías hacer, es proteger toda la hoja, y desbloquear las que pretendas que sean editables.

Por ejemplo:

```
//Seteo que la celda A1 va a ser Editable.
ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Locked = false;
//Seteo la contraseña para desbloquear la hoja.
ws.Protection.SetPassword("TuContraseña");
//Activo la protección
ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;
```

De esta manera, toda la hoja será de sólo lectura excepto la celda `A1`.

Cabe aclarar, que como le quite la protección a una celda usando `Style.Locked = false` también puede aplicarse a una columna entera

```
ws.Column(1).Style.Locked = false;
```

o a una fila entera

```
ws.Row(1).Style.Locked = false;
```

Utilicé de referencia [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20752225/5213794) y [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26235132/5213794) de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Gracias @Juan Salvador Portugal lo he colocado en mi código y todo funciona correctamente ya me bloquea lo que necesito.